# How can I evenly distribute skill among teams.

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, operations-research

Suppose I have 5 groups of 5 players.  Each player has a skill rating from 1 to 100.

I'd like to evenly distribute players, 1 from each group, into teams of 5.

Suppose the $i^{th}$ player in team $j$ has ranking $r_{ji}$.  When I break each player into a team (one player from each group) their team's ranking is the average ranking of the comprising players

$$R_j = \dfrac{1}{5} \sum_i  r_{ji} \>.$$

I would like to minimize 
$$\sum_j (R_j - \bar{r} ) ^2 \>. $$

Where $\bar{r}$ is the mean ranking of all players.

Is there a recommended strategy, or approach, to this kind of optimization? How can I best assign players to a teams to minimize this quantity?

Comment: How are the rankings done??? Is it from 1 to 25 by comparing all 25 players  or are the players rank internally from 1 to 5 in their own initial groups?

Comment: It seems that there are only a few combinations, why don't you check them all (with a computer)?

Comment: You can use gradient descent.

Comment: @dtldarek Yea, I could do that.  Thought this could be more fun.

Comment: @s.singh Except this is a discrete problem.

Comment: @NewGuy: "Each player has a skill rating from 1 to 100."

Comment: This feels a bit like the subset sum problem, which is NP-hard. Though I don't know if the restriction on the size of the subsets makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can code this as a mixed integer linear program, with a quadratic objective function. Good quality solvers should have no problem with it. You can also apply a variety of metaheuristics to get good (but not provably optimal) solutions to it. A colleague and I published a [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/0740817X.2014.953643) on a somewhat more complex (in terms of number of attributes/metrics and side constraints) variant of this problem.